# which apps are these!! we stay in brazil

Tags: applications, search

I want to know the name of these apps .. i want to track my sister.. she doesnt let me touch her phone.. i just want to know the name of these apps....
[image]

i want to know the name of the apps.. the 3 notifications indicates the app..   i searched it but i couldnt find.. i hope if anybody can tell me.. we stay in brazil.. so the app might be common to brazilian

Comment: What is the Phone model?

Answer (score 0):

The first looks like a completed download. The second is the voicemail icon, just the regular phone app. (Note that I'm not sure about the first one)

Comment: Can you support your answer with links to apps or icons with context explaining what you mentioned briefly?

Comment: The completed download, I took a guess as it is the most likely thing that would result in a tick. Most downloads, whether using chrome or some other 3rd party browser/app (like es file explorer) result in such a tick. The voicemail one - that is a universal symbol for voicemail! Just google "voicemail" and all the images are of that. Even landline telephones have that symbol.

Comment: I suspect you are wrong on the first count, and probably correct on the 2nd. Note: Chrome or Firefox indicate completed downloads with a fully-shaded down-pointing arrow with a horizontal bar below it.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I know. But I apps like es file explorer display such icons for completed downloads.